# How to remove store code from media image path in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I'm working with Testimonial Pro extension and it's using the following function to display the image :

src="getUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA). $testimonial->getTestimonialImg() ?>"

However this generates image path with store code e.g. http://domain.com/us/media/image.jpg
which doesn't work. 
One of my other extensions requires me to add store codes to URL in order to display language properly, so disabling it is not an option.

So how do I modify this script to call an URL that does not include store code?

Comment: Instead of modifying all extensions, isn't it easier to modify extension that requires store code in urls? for example, you can add GetUrlWithStoreCode method in your extension's helper and call it when you need to add store to the url.

Comment: It's about a Facebook Like extension that requires a different URL (for different store views) in order to pick up the correct language when sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one of these parameters:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters#parameter_2_-_routeparams

My bet would be

```
src="<?php Mage::getUrl('media',array('_type'=>'direct_link')) . $testimonial->getTestimonialImg() ?>"
```